# calculating new value function in 2 ways

Tags: reinforcement-learning

why the 2 following codes gives different results :

the question is about calculating new value function using value iteration algo (reinforcement learning)

I have 163 states and 2 actions

```
# mdp_data['transition_probs'] has shape (163,163,2)
# mdp_data['reward'] has shape (163,)
# mdp_data['value'] has shape (163,)
# num = 163
# tolerance = 0.0995

I have to return 1 if the algo converges in one iteration
seems that new V is not the same in the 2 codes bellow
```

code 1:

```
    iters = 0
    Psa = mdp_data['transition_probs']
    num = mdp_data['num_states']
    R = mdp_data['reward'].reshape((num,1))
    V=mdp_data['value'].reshape((num,1))
    
    
    while True:
        V = mdp_data['value']
        V = V.reshape((num,1))
        P0 = Psa[:,:,0]@V
        P1 = Psa[:,:,1]@V
        NewV = R + gamma* np.maximum(P0,P1)
        #NewV = NewV.reshape((num,1))
        mdp_data['value'] = NewV.reshape((num,))
        iters+=1
        
        if (max(np.abs(NewV-V)))< tolerance:
            break
        
    return iters==1
```

code 2:

```
while True:
        iters += 1

        value = mdp_data['value']
        new_value = mdp_data['reward'] + gamma * value.dot(transition_probs).max(axis=1)
        mdp_data['value'] = new_value

        if np.max(np.abs(value - new_value)) < tolerance:
            break

    return iters==1
```

I tried code 1 and code 2

they should give the same result